# fgets() not responding to PuTTY command

Tags: c, embedded, putty, fgets

I am having some trouble interfacing with an embedded project using PuTTY and fgets().  I am asking the user for input in the PuTTY terminal, and running register reads/writes based on the command.

I believe that the issue lies with PuTTY, as the code works with Tera Term (I want to use PuTTY so I can use the local line editing feature).

The relevant section of code is simple:

```
int main(void) {
    bool connected = false;
    bool quit = false;
    char strcom[100];
    /* other variable declarations */

    connected = device_good(); // read version register, if correct, return true

    if (connected) {
        printf("Connected to LAN8770 device...\r\n");
    } else {
        quit = true;
    }

    while (!quit) {
        printf(">> ");
        fgets(strcom, sizeof(strcom), stdin);

        /* rest of code and input processing */
    }
}
```

When debugging, I see that the code never progresses beyond the `fgets()` call.  However, I know that PuTTY can receive information from the processor, because I do see output from the `printf()` statement in the `if (connected)` block.

I have read that PuTTY will sometimes only send the carriage return (`\r`), which wouldn't work with `fgets()`, but I have the "implicit LF in every CR" setting checked:

[image: PuTTY Terminal Settings]

Is there a setting in PuTTY that I am missing?  Or is it an issue with my code that, for some reason, causes misbehavior with PuTTY?

Any suggestions/ideas are appreciated!

-Sean

edit: note that the "implicit CR in every LF" option doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Try first with `fgetc` to see if it can receive anything at all.

Comment: `fgetc` works.  I can type a character, press enter, and it prints back.

Comment: Is your `stdin`  actually  mapped to serial port?

Comment: Yes.  As I said in the original post, this code works with other serial terminals (e.g. Tera Term).

Comment: Print the codes of whatever you get with `fgetc` and see what you get when pressing Enter. Maybe you need "Implicit CR with LF"

Comment: It seems that if it works in TeraTerm and not in PuTTY, then it is not an SO question. i.e. it is not about your software or programming, but about a third-party application.  If you wanted to modify the low-level I/O code in your target to support echo and back-space line editing that would be a legitimate question.

Comment: Eugene, I tried the implicit CR in every LF setting, and that did not solve the problem.  Clifford, that seems reasonable.  I will remove the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you do what I suggested? Like to print what it is receiving on Enter?

Comment: Modifying the low-level I/O routines to accept different line end format may be the easier solution.  If you accept `\n` only, it will work for CR+LF and LF conventions.  You may want to strip any stray CR too when followed by an LF.

Comment: Eugene, when I press enter, I get back "0d" using `ctype.h` and `printf("%02x", c);`

Comment: Clifford, are you suggesting that i modify how `fgets()` itself works?

Comment: Only that? It's CR.

Comment: Well that would explain it.  Doing some more digging, the "Implict LF with CR" setting apparently only works for how the terminal interprets info sent by the server.  I can send a line feed using Ctrl+J.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like PuTTY doesn't send a line feed when Enter is pressed.  It only sends a carriage return.  Appending `Ctrl+J` to the end of the line gets the job done, but it's not a great solution.  Thanks to Eugene Sh. for the troubleshooting technique.

As Clifford pointed out, this question is not really an SO question. I have voted to close it.

Comment: It looks like your code is running on a moderately sophisticated system and not bare-metal hardware, so you may also be able to use something like `stty` (or various ioctls in your pogram) to configure the serial port to translate incoming CR to LF (icrnl)